# python pyperclip.copy does not work in Ubuntu 22.10 (Wayland) because printenv "DISPLAY" returns 0. What to do?

Tags: python, wayland

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10, with Wayland. I tried in a python script 'pyperclip.copy("xyz")'. Nothing copied to clipboard. 'printenv "DISPLAY"' under Wayland returns :0, and that, I am told is why pyperclip fails. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with pyperclip, by switching at login to Xorg, which I found out how to do by a google search, which search I should have done before asking the question. Problem solved